# My Google Nearby Search API is returning the same location for every entry

Tags: google-places-api

I have ran this query 100 times.  All of my locations that are returned have the same location.latitude location.longitude and viewport.  I NEED the latitudes and longitudes.  Just hitting postman is giving me incorrect values.  [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=[A](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%5BA) LATITUDE],[A Longitude]&key=[TOKEN]&pagetoken=&rankby=distance

even not using rankby distance.  Every single entry has the same values.  How can I fix this. What AM i Doing wrong.

Comment: I noticed that iF I use a keyword to search through names or something then it returns individual lat/longs that are different per place.   Is there any other param that I can use to search every location that will trigger this?

Answer (score 0):

I remembered that I had seen this work before. The issue was that I was supplying so many latitude and longitude precision that somehow that was affecting the results.  When I trimmed the precision down to the thousandths, voila, latitude and longitudes.  You can see this for yourself by trying to hit the api with a full lat/lng from maps.google.com, and then trimming it down.